# ios scrollview - subview out of bounds vertically

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, scroll, constraints, autolayout

I have a dilemma that I cant get my head around to why it act as it does. I have some images that describes the problem. I have a sb:

[image: xcode dump]

note! the Image view and the mapview are on top of eachother. Toggling hidden or not depending if I have coords or not to display on map.

I add some dynamic text programmatically under the Sb UIView (and set some constraints. so it looks like this in the end:

[image: xcode dump]

Problem now is that if i scroll down a bit so that it looks like this:

[image: xcode dump]

Then if I hit the mapbutton to go to nextview that containts a bigger mapview and then return to this view. The scrollview is stuck with parts of the map under the navbar. I can ofc force a scrolldown and see the rest of the mapview but when I release it bounces back and party hides under the navbar once again.

I dont understand shit. And tell me if you want me to try to explain this better its 1.30am and  my eyes can barely stay open. But still - any help or pointers are valuable to me.

/Pedro

Comment: Scrolling to top of your `UIScrollView` by sending `[scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,0) animated:NO];` when the page is presented again doesn't work?

Comment: Tnx mate. It did work if I put it in viewWillAppear.
I tried viewDidAppear, viewDidLoad and viewDidLayoutSubviews first but got nothing. But at least I got it to work now :-)
Tnx a bunch m8 :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can scroll to the top of a `UIScrollView` using `[scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,0) animated:NO];`.